# Simple BASH script treating flags as commands

Tags: linux, bash, gcc

I've been trying to write a **really** simple bash script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
gcc –Werror –std=c99 client.c –o client
gcc –Werror –std=c99 server.c –o server
```

Each of the commands works fine when input manually, but from the scripts it treats each of the flags as a standalone command, resulting in the following output:

```
[elad@localhost HW1]$ ./compile
gcc: –Werror: No such file or directory
gcc: –std=c99: No such file or directory
gcc: –o: No such file or directory
gcc: –Werror: No such file or directory
gcc: –std=c99: No such file or directory
gcc: –o: No such file or directory
[elad@localhost HW1]$
```

I'm using a weird specialized RedHat distro provided by my university.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In

```
gcc –Werror
```

this character: `–` is not a dash (`-`), but an [en-dash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm).

Replace that and/or use a different editor.

Comment: That's what I get for copy&pasting code from a PDF. I can't believe I overlooked that! Silly me! Thanks!